# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error... why?

Tags: java, android

I'm a bit lost on this one. How can I get an OutOfBounds? Is there a size limit (besides sizeof (int))?

Maybe because **multiple threads** can come here? The UI thread and a Service thread?

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at
>   kenyu73.realsignal.DatabaseWrapper.getSignalValues(DatabaseWrapper.java:137) at
>   kenyu73.realsignal.DatabaseWrapper.getSignalValues(DatabaseWrapper.java:116) at
>   kenyu73.realsignal.BarScaleGraph$buildGraphThread.drawGraph(BarScaleGraph.java:128)
>   at
>   kenyu73.realsignal.BarScaleGraph$buildGraphThread.execute(BarScaleGraph.java:94)
>   at
>   kenyu73.realsignal.BarScaleGraph$buildGraphThread.run(BarScaleGraph.java:74)

Also, I'm calling this classes methods with a **static instance**. I'm thinking threads are competing for the same variables??? Thoughts?

**BarScaleGraph class**

```
ContentValues[] values = DatabaseWrapper.getInstance().getSignalValues(getContentResolver(), signal_type, false);
```

**DatabaseWrapper class**

```
private static final DatabaseWrapper    instance    = new DatabaseWrapper();

// grab static instance so we only have one db wrapper
public static DatabaseWrapper getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

. . . .

public ContentValues[] getSignalValues(ContentResolver cr, int signal_type_id, boolean bGroupByLatLon) {

    String sWhere = "signal_type_id=" + signal_type_id;

    Cursor cursor;

    if (bGroupByLatLon) {
        cursor = cr.query(CONSTS.CONTENT_URI_GRP_LATLNG, null, sWhere, null, null);
    } else {
        cursor = cr.query(CONSTS.CONTENT_URI_LOGGER, null, sWhere, null, null);
    }

    ContentValues[] values = new ContentValues[cursor.getCount()];

    int count = 0;
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            values[count] = new ContentValues(); // <--- LINE 137
            values[count].put("signal_value", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("signal_value")));
            values[count].put("latitude", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude")));
            values[count].put("longitude", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude")));
            values[count].put("timestamp", cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("timestamp")));
            values[count].put("network", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("network")));

            count++;

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    return values;
}
```

**EDIT**: Going to try this - add **synchronized** to the instance

```
// grab static instance so we only have one db wrapper
public static synchronized DatabaseWrapper getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: You never declared an array in your snippet.  Posting this would help us solve your issue.

Comment: In which like you get the exception?

Comment: This doesn't happen alot. I've only had two reports of it. This method is called by multiple threads. I'm wondering if that is the cause? There is a UI and a service thread.

Comment: updated post to include possible threading as the issue...

Comment: Did you try to have the method synchronized?

Comment: @TacB0sS: I was reading on that. I may have to do something like: synchronized(DatabaseWrapper.getinstance().getSignalValues(); .... something in this nature if threading is the cause.

Comment: public synchronized ContentValues[] getSignalValues(...)

Comment: @TacB0sS: i've read that doing a sync on the method only stops 1 thread from reading the same line in that method that the other thread is using. It doesn't cause one thread to wait before accessing that method until the previous completes the method. There are a number of topics on SO on this, but I've seen arguments both ways.

Comment: Did you give it a go? Does the problem persists?

Comment: @TacB0sS not yet... still have an hour left with my "real" job. T.J. Crowder is saying that it shouldn't need to be synchronized, but I'm going to implement a few changes recommended here in some fashion.

Comment: The update you have added would not effect the race condition... only synchronizing the method itself, see my update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess this is a race condition, where the count is change between threads... try to synchronize the method:

```
public synchronized ContentValues[] getSignalValues(...){
    ...
}
```

If the previous does not fit you, there is always this:

```
public ContentValues[] method1(...){
    synchronized (monitor1) {
        ...
    }
}

public ContentValues[] method2(...){
    synchronized (monitor2) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This would solve the issue, but I would try to prevented this sort of methodology using different architecture.

Comment: ...very possible. I wonder if I can use synchronized on my getInstance() instead. This way any method is safe? Just guessing... I'm not a thread expert. I can make them, but not effective explain them (=

Comment: If this is a race condition issue, your suggestion would not overcome it. both threads would acquire the instance in a synchronous order, and both would call the "getSignalValues" method asynchronously.

Comment: Good point. The issue is that I have alot of public methods that are multi-thread accessible. I guess I'd have to add synchronized on all methods in this call. This is all assuming its a race condition. I have good arguments that having multiple threads in one method isn't possible as each would get its own instance. I'm note sure if using a static instance mutes that though. I'd think a static instance would make all methods static inherently.

Comment: Its going to be hard to prove quickly if this works, but I'm going to accept this as an answer. The only logical thing it can be is a race condition. If it were a count/loop thing, I'd have 1000's of reported errors and I'd see it myself... I will rewrite the loop though.

Answer (score 2):

The only reasonable answer is that `cursor.getCount()` is returning a number lower than the number of loops that your `do..while` loop makes. I'm not seeing an error in the logic of your `do..while` loop (though it's unusual logic; see below).

My guess would be that it's a live cursor, and something else is <s>deleting</s> adding relevant rows while your loop is running. The only real way to find out will be to add instrumentation to the code so you can see what `cursor.getCount()` returned, what `count` was at the beginning of each loop iteration, etc.

If you don't really care *why* and just want it to stop happening, you could use a `List` instead:

```
public ContentValues[] getSignalValues(ContentResolver cr, int signal_type_id, boolean bGroupByLatLon) {

    String sWhere = "signal_type_id=" + signal_type_id;

    Cursor cursor;

    if (bGroupByLatLon) {
        cursor = cr.query(CONSTS.CONTENT_URI_GRP_LATLNG, null, sWhere, null, null);
    } else {
        cursor = cr.query(CONSTS.CONTENT_URI_LOGGER, null, sWhere, null, null);
    }

    List<ContentValues> values = new LinkedList<ContentValues>();
    ContentValues entry;

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        entry = new ContentValues();
        entry.put("signal_value", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("signal_value")));
        entry.put("latitude", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude")));
        entry.put("longitude", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude")));
        entry.put("timestamp", cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("timestamp")));
        entry.put("network", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("network")));
        values.add(entry);
    }
    cursor.close();

    return values.toArray(new ContentValues[values.size()]);
}
```

*(Or code to that effect.)*

There I've used a temporary linked list so I don't care what `cursor.getCount` returns, converting it into an array when we're done. I've also used the more common idiom for looping cursors (since cursors start out just before the first row, `while (cursor.moveToNext())` is a handy way to loop), not (again) that I saw a logic fault in your `do..while`, but I like the simplicity and directness of `while (cursor.moveToNext())`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This method gets called from the UI and from a service thread. Do you think two threads accessing the same method could cause this? I'm updating my initial question with more info.

Comment: @kenyu73: I'm not seeing how. The cursor isn't shared between the threads, everything's local to the function. Two threads calling it at the same time should be just fine.

Comment: The method is called using a static instance. Would that make a difference? xyz = "DatabaseWrapper.getInstance().getSignalValues(..);"

Comment: @kenyu73: Nope, because you're not using instance fields within the function. The cursor is a local, and each call to the function gets its own local variables.

Comment: I have no idea then. I only have 2 reports of this in my dev console, but if it isn't thread related, then I'm a tad stumped.

Answer (score 0):

What about this,

```
int count = 0;
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
ContentValues[] values = new ContentValues[cursor.getCount()];
cursor.moveToFirst();
do {
        if(cursor.getCount() >= count)
        {
        values[count].put("signal_value", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("signal_value")));
        values[count].put("latitude", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude")));
        values[count].put("longitude", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude")));
        values[count].put("timestamp", cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("timestamp")));
        values[count].put("network", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("network")));
        }
        count++;
    }  while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
cursor.close();
```

Comment: @kmb385 - I not mention while part.

Comment: That would be a hack that would probably catch the error, but in theory, the getCount() should be dead on.

Comment: @kenyu73 - yes, you have to declare int for cursor.getCount() and use that variable in your code.

Comment: @user370305: His `do..while`, though not the way it's usually done, is fine. His logic is successfully only looping when there's meant to be a row under the cursor.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - the code line 137 values[count] = new ContentValues(); is throwing exception the the only reason for this is values has exceed the array size. what about this?

Comment: @user370305: Right. No disputing that. The question is **why**. His loop's body should only execute when there's a row under the cursor, the logic is unusual, but not obviously flawed. There's an up-front `getCount() > 0` check, a `moveToFirst` taking him to the first record, which the body processes, followed by a `moveToNext`. If `moveToNext` succeeded (there's a second record), the loop body is executed a second time. So it's not a `do..while` vs. `while` thing. It's something else.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and user370305: I'm wondering if its because my class methods are called from a static instance....and maybe need to use synchronized in some form.

Answer (score 0):

Your using a do...while loop, the do while loop will execute an extra iteration because the condition is checked after each iteration, not before.  The code gets past your guard condition and enters the loop, which then executes 2x when there is one result.

Switch the loop to a while loop and this should work fine.

```
int count = 0;
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            values[count] = new ContentValues();
            values[count].put("signal_value", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("signal_value")));
            values[count].put("latitude", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude")));
            values[count].put("longitude", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude")));
            values[count].put("timestamp", cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("timestamp")));
            values[count].put("network", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("network")));

            count++;

        }
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Comment: No, his loop is fine. It's a bit convoluted, but it's fine. He pre-checks that the count is greater than zero, moves to the first row, processes it in the body of the loop, and then moves to the next row. `moveToNext` returns `false` if the cursor ends up not on a row, and the loop ends.

Comment: @kmb385: Pretty sure he's using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount()

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure what the problem is, you can do it in a safer way:

```
List<ContentValues> values = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
        value.put("signal_value", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("signal_value")));
        values.add(value);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
// ...
return values.toArray(new ContentValues[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. If I cant figure out the cause, ArrayList is a good hack to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

cursor.moveToFirst could be returning false. Try wrapping that in an if statement:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  do....
}
```

Comment: That just raises the question of why `getCount` is returning `> 0` but `moveToFirst` is returning `false`.